# Keep Last Repeated Row Differing by a Column

Tags: r

Some rows are repeats except by a column. So, all rows with likeness on all columns except one, I want to keep the very last repeat.

Example:

```
NC       12/08/19        4
NC       12/08/19        4
NC       12/08/19        7
NC       12/08/19        9
```

To...

```
NC       12/08/19        9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'col1', 'col2' and `slice` the last row

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(col1, col2) %>%
    slice(n())
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   col1, col2 [1]
#  col1  col2      col3
#  <chr> <chr>    <int>
#1 NC    12/08/19     9
```

---

Or with `base R`, use `duplicated` to create a logical vector with `fromLast = TRUE` and subset the rows based on that

```
df1[!duplicated(df1[c('col1', 'col2')], fromLast = TRUE),]
#    col1     col2 col3
#4   NC 12/08/19    9
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("NC", "NC", "NC", "NC"), col2 = c("12/08/19", 
"12/08/19", "12/08/19", "12/08/19"), col3 = c(4L, 4L, 7L, 9L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```